# How to export jasper report to an existing excel file

Tags: jasper-reports

I have an jasper report that I can easily export as an .xls (using preview function in jasper). However I want Jasper to export to an existing excel file (say in my desktop "~/Desktop/output.xls )

I think its something related to Interface XlsExporterConfiguration but I am not sure how or what to do. I'd like to do something like:

1. Start Jaspersoft Studio IDE.
2. Open JRXML file.
3. Run JRXML file to generate (preview) a report.
4. Click **File >> Export >> Append** to append report to an existing spreadsheet.

The **File >> Export >> Append** isn't how to do this from within the IDE. Is there a way?

Comment: Do you have some code to show? Maybe at least the language? What is your status now? It is a little hard to help right now.

Comment: No code, I was hoping for a more of a GUI solution, something like go here do this type.

Comment: Still not clear what you have now and how you create the report.

Comment: its a jasperstudio report. I can paste the jrxml file if you need

Comment: "to an existing excel file", you like to append, overwrite?, use as template?, do you know how to program in java? see docs http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/5008/export-to-xls-xlsx/17668/with-java

Comment: If you can use `.csv` files, then you can [concatenate](http://superuser.com/a/111832/9067) the files using a command prompt (convert to Excel when finished, if necessary). Otherwise, you'll likely have to implement a Java solution as per Petter's comment.

Comment: Thanks you @DaveJarvis and Peter I will look into this an give you an update